# How can I compare 2 dictionaries?

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary

I have two dictionaries

```
dict_a = {'x' : 2, 'y' : 3.5, 'z' : 4}
dict_b = {'bob' : ['x', 'y'], 'john' : ['z', 'x'], 'bill' : ['y']}
```

I want to compare the two dictionaries and create a new one with the keys from `dict_b` and values from `dict_a`if the values from `dict_b` match. I would expect to see:

```
new_dict = {'bob' : [2, 3.5], 'john' : [4, 2], 'bill' : [3.5]}
```

I have tried the following code:

```
for name, guess in dict_b.items():
    if guess == i in dict_a.values():
        new_dict[name].append(i)  
print(new_dict)
```

I get the error `NameError: name 'i' is not defined`but I'm not sure how to define 'i'.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if guess == i in dict_a.values():
```

This does not do what you expect it to do. Python here chains the operators, so your test is equivalent to the following:

```
(guess == i) and (i in dict_a.values())
```

So it’s not like executing a for loop here where you iterate a variable `i` in the dictionary values.

Furthermore, you actually need to collect the values from those multiple keys, so what you would want to do here is the following:

```
new_dict = {}
for name, guesses in dict_b.items():
    result = []
    for guess in guesses:
        if guess in dict_a:
            result.append(dict_a[guess])
    new_dict[name] = result
```

Then, you can also use list comprehensions to shorten this:

```
new_dict = {}
for name, guesses in dict_b.items():
    new_dict[name] = [dict_a[guess] for guess in guesses if guess in dict_a]
```

And finally, you could even combine this with a dict comprehension:

```
new_dict = { name: [dict_a[guess] for guess in guesses if guess in dict_a] for name, guesses in dict_b.items() }
```

Answer (score 3):

well like so:

```
new_dict = {name: [dict_a[k] for k in dict_b[name]] for name in` dict_b.keys()}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a simple dict comprehension:

```
>>> {k: [dict_a.get(x,x) for x in v] for k, v in dict_b.items()}
{'bob': [2, 3.5], 'john': [4, 2], 'bill': [3.5]}
```

This replaces values with those from `dict_a` if they exist. Otherwise, keeps those from `dict_b` (the second argument in `.get(x,x)`).

Alternatively, fix the original code this way:

```
new_dict = {}
for name, guess in dict_b.items():
    new_dict[name] = []
    for value in guess:
        if value in dict_a:
            new_dict[name].append(dict_a[value])  
print(new_dict)
```